# Анимация css, всплывающее сообщение

Tags: html, css, html5

```css
.msg {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000000c7;
  max-width: 500px;
  left: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 80%));
  top: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  z-index: 51000;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: identifier 4s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.msg:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused
}

@keyframes identifier {
  1% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  99.99% {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: auto
  }
  100% {
    pointer-events: none
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='msg'>Текст</div>
```

Не удается настроить анимацию, как сделать чтобы появлялась медленно, затем держалась секунды 3 и исчезала. Но исчезала в том случаи, если нет курсора над сообщением.

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```css
.msg {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000000c7;
  max-width: 500px;
  left: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 80%));
  top: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  z-index: 51000;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: identifier 6s ease forwards;
}

.msg:hover {
  background-color: #f00!important;
  animation-play-state: paused
}

@keyframes identifier {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #00f;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='msg'>Текст</div>
```

Comment: Что та в примере не хочет работать...

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов Что именно не работает?